# Tensorflow: Mulitiplication of a vector with a Matrix

Tags: tensorflow

I have a vector `x = <C elements>`. I want to multiple it with a matrix `Z = <C x C elements>`. This will give an output of `<1xC>` matrix ( `<C>` vector).
I can just multiply them if I have one samples only for each.

But during training, I have tensors `x = <NxC>` and `Z = <NxCxC>`, where 'N' is my mini-batch size. How can I achieve the above computation in this case. Plain `tf.matmul()` return error complaining about dimensions.

`ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'Channel/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,2], [?,2,2].`

Thanks,

Vishnu Raj

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Expand the last dimension of tensor `x`. Its shape is now `(N, C)`.
2. Multiply tensors `Z` and `x` with broadcasting. The shape of the resulting tensor is `(N, C, C)`.
3. Sum over the last dimension of that tensor.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 2
C = 3

Z = tf.ones((N, C, C))  # Shape=(N, C, C)
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(0, N*C, dtype=tf.float32), shape=(N, C))  # Shape=(N, C)
mul = tf.reduce_sum(Z * x[:, :, None], axis=-1)  # Shape=(N, C)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(mul))
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. 
For correct maths, I have to put axis = 1.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that's possible (this depends on how you define your tensors). Please remember to accept and/or upvote the answer if it was useful.